# Is there a way to automatically check all check boxes in group A by checking another individual check box with DocuSign API

Tags: docusignapi

let's say I defined mutilple check boxes with DocuSign eSignature Java SDK, each of the check box been given unique Tab Label,  then group them together in tabs group A and all the check boxes in tabs group A are mandatory (with Validator).

Is there any way that I can define another individual check box (call it B) in the envelope,  by checking the check box B will automaticly check/uncheck all the check boxes in tabs group A by using DocuSign Java SDK or eSignature REST API.

I would appreciate it if any one could provide a solution, thank you^_^.

Comment: If the answer helps you out, be sure to upvote and accept. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, no. I would instead suggest playing with [Tab Replication](https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/Why-is-Data-Replicating-in-Multiple-Fields-Using-Data-Population-Scope) feature. It might serve as a good replacement for this requirement.

Here's an example use case...

Let's assume you have a job application that asks the applicant to specify which languages she is familiar with. At the top of the list of languages, there is a checkbox labeled "All". If the user selects this option, all checkboxes next to the individual languages are hidden from view. Otherwise, the user can select the languages that are applicable.

Once the user completes her signing, the business logic of your app can check if that "all" checkbox was selected and interpret it to mean that the user is comfortable with all languages, otherwise, you would check the individual values of the other checkboxes.

Here is how you would build that envelope from scratch: Notice that each checkbox references its parent via `conditionalParentLabel`. `conditionalParentValue": "off"`tells DocuSign to hide the children from view if the parent is checked.

```
POST /envelopes

{
    "emailSubject": "Please sign this document set",
    "documents": [
        {
            "documentBase64": "JVBERi0xLj...UlRU9GCg==",
            "name": "Test Doc",
            "fileExtension": "pdf",
            "documentId": "1"
        }
    ],
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [
            {
                "email": "test@test.com",
                "name": "Matthew Roknich",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "tabs": {
                    "checkboxTabs": [
                        {
                            "tabLabel": "all",
                            "locked": "false",
                            "xPosition": "100",
                            "yPosition": "100",
                            "documentId": "1",
                            "pageNumber": "1"
                        },
                         {
                            "tabLabel": "english",
                            "locked": "false",
                            "xPosition": "130",
                            "yPosition": "110",
                            "documentId": "1",
                            "pageNumber": "1",
                            "conditionalParentLabel": "all",
                            "conditionalParentValue": "off"
                        },
                         {
                            "tabLabel": "spanish",
                            "locked": "false",
                            "xPosition": "160",
                            "yPosition": "110",
                            "documentId": "1",
                            "pageNumber": "1",
                            "conditionalParentLabel": "all",
                            "conditionalParentValue": "off"
                        },
                         {
                            "tabLabel": "french",
                            "locked": "false",
                            "xPosition": "190",
                            "yPosition": "110",
                            "documentId": "1",
                            "pageNumber": "1",
                            "conditionalParentLabel": "all",
                            "conditionalParentValue": "off"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
          ]
    },
  "status": "sent"
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mr.Matthew Roknich, wish you have a nice day, thank you.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help. If you have a moment, please upvote and accept the answer if it was helpful.